# Protractor - checkbox with dynamic id cannot be defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I need to define a specific check box and (later on) click on it to complete the account creation. The problem is that part of the input id is dynamic and changes with each run. Therefore, my approach below is not working:

```
var nativeChannels = element(by.css("label[for='dp-native-9597']"));
```

When I inspect the element, it displays the following:

```
div class="switch"input id="dp-native-9597" type="checkbox" ng-model="controls.allNativeChannels" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" autocomplete="off">label for="dp-native-9597">/label/div

label for="dp-native-9597"/label
```

I searched for a way to put a wild character after `dp-native-` but looks like this is not allowed. Is there any way to define this type of check box, so that I could move on with tests?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: did you try with ng-model="control.allNativeChannels"?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below xpath.
.//label [contains(@for,"dp-native-")]

Answer (score 0):

There are wild card selectors in CSS (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) :

```
[attribute^=value]  a[href^="https"]    Selects every <a> element whose href attribute value begins with "https"
[attribute$=value]  a[href$=".pdf"] Selects every <a> element whose href attribute value ends with ".pdf"
[attribute*=value]  a[href*="w3schools"]    Selects every <a> element whose href attribute value contains the substring "w3schools"
```

Try one of these. I think you might search like this:

```
$(".switch[id*='dp-native'] label")
```

or by model (http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.model) :

```
element(by.model('controls.allNativeChannels')).$('label');
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and links - use of wild cards did the trick and put me in control of this tricky check box!